# JSP not able to connect to mysql database on tomcat7

Tags: jsp, jdbc

Hi i am new to jsp & was trying to display some data from mysql db. For that i have installed JDK1.7,MySQL Server 5.5,mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar as connector on tomcat 7 server. i have created a file in **%CATALINA_HOME%webapps/ROOT/ws/** folder i.e. **index.jsp** with code

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:test?user=root;password=sumant";
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
%>


<html><body>


<%
Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "", "");
statement = connection.createStatement();
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM store");

while (rs.next()) {
out.println(rs.getString("name")+"<br>");
}

rs.close();
%>


</body></html>
```

And on calling url: **http://localhost:8080/ws/index.jsp** i am getting

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /ws/index.jsp at line 14

11: 
12: 
13: <%
14: Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
15: connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "", "");
16: statement = connection.createStatement();
17: rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM store");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:567)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:456)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
    org.apache.jsp.ws.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:98)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.ws.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:78)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Now i am not getting what is wrong here. Please help me to connect to mysql Database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the mysql_connector/j driver jar file in the class path. then connect using

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

also your connection url should have the mysql port which is 3306

```
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root;password=sumant";
```

Comment: still its not working. i have downloaded the connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and the Driver.class is inside org\gjt\mm\mysql directory in jar file.

Comment: why are you puting it in that directory?try and put it in the lib

Answer (score 3):

Connect using `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class (so called JDBC driver) rather than `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`. Any third party API needs be added in classpath in order to use it. So, The JAR for this needs to be visible in Tomcat. So, I would suggest to place `mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar` at physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project which is **ws** in your case.

In earlier days, I have experienced `ClassNotFoundException` if jar is not at physical location. Then restarting Tomcat should work.